# DeviceId generated for Android mobile push

Tags: mobile, mobilepush-android

I just implemented mobile push for my android application and can successfully register test phones and send push messages to them.

My question concerns the device ID / Subscriber key I am seeing in debug and which are used to identify my devices in the Exact Target Interface. For some reason, those do not match my device ID when browsing through the cellphones preferences. Am I missing something?

Example:
Cellphone subscriberkey/device ID: 6fa61ca351759310184b9c79ee81966
Actual device ID/uuid: 3D6CDD0D61C81B45

Any advice would be much appreciated.Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing in the logs is the MD5 hash of your device ID.